# Como renombrar todas las variables de una dataframe?

Tags: r

Tengo una DF en R donde todas la variables tienen data-variable1, data-variable2, data-variable3.... como hago para eliminar la parte "**data-**" de todas las variables?

Comment: Añade cómo has intentado resolverlo.

Answer (score 0):

Encontre la solucion

```
names(DF) <- sub("data-", "", names(DF))
```